# Android - Make a button disappear after having a in app billing successfully purchased

Tags: android, android-fragments, in-app-billing

I'm new to Android, and I'm trying to implement in app billing for my app. What I have is a button that takes you to the InAppBillingActivity, and the activity does it's thing. What I want to do is when the purchase is successful, the button that took you to that activity will disappear. I can't get it to disappear, and I might not be doing it right. I have to press the back button to go back to the fragment it came from and it seems to not be doing it right. So here is my code:

```
public class InAppBillingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "com.android.inappbilling";
    public IabHelper mHelper;
    private Button btnInAppBilling;

    public boolean isPurchased;
    private CheckListGatherFragment checkListGatherFragment;
    static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_app_billing);
        btnInAppBilling = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInAppBilling);

        checkListGatherFragment = new CheckListGatherFragment();
        String base64EncodedPublicKey = "";

        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
            {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                            result);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                }
            }
       });
  }

public void buyClick(View view){
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data)
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle error
            return;
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            consumeItem();
            btnInAppBilling.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
};

public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
            return;
        } else {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {

                if (result.isSuccess()) {

                  //Here is where I am trying to get it to disappear 
                 checkListGatherFragment.btnPurchase.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 //Tried a boolean to get it to disappear
                    isPurchased = true;
                } else {
                    // handle error
                    return;
                }
            }
        };

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}


}
```

Here is some of my fragment:

```
private InAppBillingActivity activity;
public  Button btnPurchase;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   btnPurchase = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPurchase);
   activity = new InAppBillingActivity();
   setOnClick();
   //tried to do it this way
   if (activity.isPurchased == true){
      btnPurchase.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
}

public void setOnClick() {
    btnPurchase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CheckListGatherFragment.this.getActivity(), InAppBillingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //tried doing it this way
            if (activity.isPurchased == true){
                btnPurchase.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
 } 

//tried doing it this way
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (activity.isPurchased == true){
        btnPurchase.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

I'm trying all different ways to try to get the button disappear, but I can't make it happen. The purchase is successful, but it won't make the button disappear. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're going back to your fragment, it is already created, so neither onCreateView nor onResume will be called.

What you can do is implement onActivityResult in your calling fragment, use startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode), and have your InAppBillingActivity return a result. Here's how:

Make these changes in your calling Fragment:

```
public void setOnClick() {
    btnPurchase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CheckListGatherFragment.this.getActivity(), InAppBillingActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
 } 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == InAppBillingActivity.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        btnPurchase.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        //handle error here
    }
}
```

And these changes in your InAppBillingActivity:

```
public static final int RESULT_SUCCESS = 1;
public static final int RESULT_FAILED = 0;

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {

                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                  InAppBillingActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_SUCCESS);
                } else {
                  InAppBillingActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_FAILED);
                }

                InAppBillingActivity.this.finish();
            }
        };
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried what you suggested, and it didn't work, but I think I'm having errors with the purchase: 06-27 12:59:54.459 13159-13159/mk E/IABUtil/Security: Purchase verification failed: missing data.
06-27 12:59:54.459 13159-13159/mk E/IabHelper: In-app billing error: Purchase signature verification FAILED for sku android.test.purchased  It seems that maybe the purchase isn't going through correctly. It says it was purchased but the verification isn't correct. What do you think? Right now, I'm just using it for test purposes.

Comment: Can't tell you much about that, I've never worked with in-app billings before. But from that error description, I'd say you're probably using the wrong Public Key.

Comment: Thanks! The code worked! I found a page on stackoverflow that solved that problem I was having.

Comment: I have one more question. How would I make sure that the button stays gone when the app resumes? The button reappears and I'm not sure how to get the activity result in the onResume(). Do you know how?

Comment: You would have to fetch information about the in-app billing, to check whether it's been purchased or not.
Search the methods inside IabHelper, and see what you can find.

Answer (score -1):

Where you have added fragment in your layout ?

Comment: you should make a comment in the main post for that question

Comment: I am unable to add comment there..it seems that I must have minimum 50 reputations. @Tharkius